# Python YAML dump is changing the double quotes with 2 single quote

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am using python yaml module to load the content from a yaml file, modified some properties, and re-writing back to a file using "yaml.dump()", however, it is changing the double quotes with 2 single quotes which is finally getting failed when it is run by ansible. Is there any way to preserve quotes that was exactly the same way when reading it

**Sample section of the code:**

```
 def update_status(playbook, masterfile):
    with open(masterfile, 'w') as file:
        #yaml.preserve_quotes = True
        playbook1 = get_default_loader()
        print(playbook1)
        print("===========================================================\n")
        print(playbook)
        yaml.dump(playbook, file, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
    file.close()


playbook=reload_queue("test.yml")

update_status(playbook,'play.yml')
```

**Content of test.yml where i am reading from :**

```
- import_playbook: "some.yaml"
  vars:
    param: "{{ hostvars['text_node']['test_server'] | default(''all'')  }}"
```

**Content of play.yml written by python yaml module :**

```
- import_playbook: "some.yaml"
  vars:
    param: '{{ hostvars[''text_node''][''test_server''] | default(''all'')  }}'
```

This problem is not seen when using **"ruamel.yaml"**. but we have a restriction to use this library. Can this be done using only yaml module?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, but you are probably mixing up `ruamel.yaml` deprecated API with the new one. You should
never use `yaml.dump(....., default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)`.

`ruamel.yaml` properly keeps the quotes as is, when you set `.preserve_quotes`:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- import_playbook: "some.yaml"
  vars:
    param: "{{ hostvars['text_node']['test_server'] | default(''all'')  }}"
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- import_playbook: "some.yaml"
  vars:
    param: "{{ hostvars['text_node']['test_server'] | default(''all'')  }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, as I already said in my question, I am using just the yaml module not ruamel. yaml due to some restriction to use any external packages.. can we achieve this with just yaml module ?

Comment: There are multiple python YAML modules. The original is Syck (YAML 1.0), PyYAML (YAML 1.1) and my ruamel.yaml (YAML 1.1 and YAML 1.2). So if it has to be PyYAML you should use that tag and not the ruamel.yaml tag. And having `yaml.preserve_quotes = True` commented out in your code also gives the impression you had been, incorrectly, using ruamel.yaml.